# get results of principal Component Analysis in R

Tags: r, tableau-api, pca

I want to get the results of PC1 and PC2 to plot courbe of both in the same graph with tableau desktop. 
How to do?

```
  data = read.csv(file="data.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";")
  data.active <- data[, 1:30]
  library(factoextra)
  res.pca <- prcomp(data.active,center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
  fviz_eig(res.pca)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a csv with the results in between R and Tableau. The code for that is written bellow :

```r
# Principal Components Analysis
res.pca <- stats::prcomp(iris[,-5],center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

# Choose number of dimension kept
factoextra::fviz_eig(res.pca)

# Some visualisation
factoextra::fviz_pca_var(res.pca)
factoextra::fviz_pca_ind(res.pca)

factoextra::fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca)

# access transformed points
str(res.pca)
res.pca$x

# save points in csv to use outside of R
utils::write.csv(x = res.pca$x, file = "path/data_pca.csv")

# Load your data and do graphs the usual way with tableau
```

I used `?prcomp` to find the data in the result, you may also push further your analysis and use some nice graphics (biplots of individual / variable, clustering, ...) with R (and import only images in Tableau) using : [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/)

Comment: If you are calling R using Tableau's SCRIPT_XXX() functions, then you don't have to write results to a CSV file. Just return the results in a vector of the same dimension as the input to the R script. SCRIPT_XXX() functions are table calcs in Tableau, so you'll have to learn how partitioning and addressing works for table calcs in general first.

Comment: That doesn't mean that writing a CSV file is a bad way to go. Sometimes that makes perfect sense. But its not the only approach, and probably not the best one if you are trying to make a fast interactive interplay between the two tools - i.e. letting people filter etc in Tableau, call R to repeat the PCA, display the results, rinse, repeat ...